# wpf chart print (system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit)

Tags: wpf, printing, charts

I'm using a Bar Chart in the system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit in a WPF/C# project. I would like to print this chart on a page, but it appears none of the binding are executed before printing. I end up with an empty square where the chart should be.

My XAML code looks like this (I've ommitted layout things)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="GUIchart" Style="{StaticResource TheGUIChartStyle}" FontSize="12">
        <chartingToolkit:BarSeries x:Name="Series" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <chartingToolkit:BarSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="Xaxis" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Interval="10" ShowGridLines="True" Orientation="X"/>
            </chartingToolkit:BarSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
        </chartingToolkit:BarSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

In c# I'm adding some titels and the bindings:

```
// set the X-axis title
Xaxis.Title = "Score in %";

// do the binding
Series.IndependentValuePath = "Name";
Series.DependentValuePath = "Score";
Series.ItemsSource = scores;
```

When debugging, this binding is actually executed before the chart is being add to the page. Nevertheless, I end up with an "empty" chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause for this the default fade-in animation in the chart.  It is described in [this forum post](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=71107).  You should be able to copy the default chart style from the source code and comment out the VSM animation.

You can download the source code for the latest DataVisualization development release [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017144834/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx).  Once you have the source, the file you want to look at is in the Core.WPF project - Themes\Generic.xaml.  All the styles can be found there.

I have not actually tried it, but you should be able to copy the BarDataPoint style and remove the "RevealStates" VisualStateGroup.

Comment: how can I "copy the default chart style from the source code"? Can you give me some information on that (I tried it in Blend, but I don't get any results)...

Comment: I added more more detail to my answer.  If you are not already using development release 4 (link in answer), I would recommend it.

Comment: I have previously encountered this problem, and this did fix it.